# Additonal Google Analytics _gat-Cookie with name is build of 2 GA-Properties. Is this normal?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

On our webseite, we run two GA-Properties parallel for different measurement purposes, let's call them UA-XXXXXX-1 and UA-XXXXXX-2. It works, but I found hat, that there are three _gat-Cookies.

The first two Cookies are logical:
**_gat-UA-XXXXXX-1
_gat-UA-XXXXXX-2**

but there is a third one where's name is combined of the two properties
**_gat-UA-XXXXXX-1UA-XXXXXX-2**

I don't know how this occurs, and if this is a proplem at all as long as the other two exists. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me a link where this combined id is seen, pls? I cannot reproduce the exception